# Selecting 4 check boxes at a time and redirect the page to the new page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Can anyone help me out please. 
I am having an image holding a check box. Like this I am having 4images with with 4 check boxes. If am selecting all the check boxes only I want to navigate to a new page directly.

if user clicked a single checkbox then the page should not redirect to the new page
if user clicked "select all" or if user selects all the check boxes one by one also the page should redirect to the new page.

Can any one please help me out and do the needful.

**HTML**

```
 <table border="1">
    <tr>
        <th><input type="checkbox" id="selectall"/></th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align="center"><input type="checkbox" class="case" name="case" value="4"/></td>
        <td align="center"><img src="images/1.jpg" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align="center"><input type="checkbox" class="case" name="case" value="4"/></td>
        <td align="center"><img src="images/2.jpg" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align="center"><input type="checkbox" class="case" name="case" value="4"/></td>
        <td align="center"><img src="images/3.jpg" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align="center"><input type="checkbox" class="case" name="case" value="4"/></td>
        <td align="center"><img src="images/4.jpg" /></td>

    </tr>

    </table>
```

**JS**

$(function(){

```
// add multiple select / deselect functionality
$("#selectall").click(function () {
      $('.case').attr('checked', this.checked);
});


$(".case").click(function(){

    if($(".case").length == $(".case:checked").length) {
        $("#selectall").attr("checked", "checked");
    } else {
        $("#selectall").removeAttr("checked");
    }

});
```

});

Comment: Could you please provide some code and maybe try to make your question a bit more clear?

Comment: pls explain your question clearly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to add `window.location.href = newURL;` after you check if all the checkboxes are selected:

```
if($(".case").length == $(".case:checked").length) {
    window.location.href = "www.stackoverflow.com";
}
```

make sure you test this condition on both occasions:

1. if user clicked a single checkbox
2. if user clicked "select all"